# Replace all whitespace but except whitespace at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all whitespace but do not want replace whitespace at the end of a string.
For example my problem:

> today is a sad day
>
> today-is-a-sad-day-

```
str = "today is a sad day ";
newstr = str.replace(/\s/g,"-");
```

Comment: [Remove all occurrences except last?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9694930)

Comment: Use trim first, to remove spaces.

Comment: So you want to keep whitespaces ant the end of string?

Comment: As you're not very clear, do you want to retain trailing whitespace? Please edit your question to show your *exact* requirements.

Comment: Example and text in your question don't match. According to your question, the result should be "today-is-a-sad-day "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code with `trim();`

```js
str = "today is a sad day ";
str = str.trim();
newstr = str.replace(/\s/g,"-");
alert(newstr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove whitespace from both sides of a string:

```js
str = "today is a sad day ";
console.log(str.trim().replace(/\s/g, "-"))
```

Comment: Just a warning, [`String#trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Browser_compatibility) is not available in IE8 if that is a requirement.

Comment: `do not want replace whitespace in the end of a string` so I think `trim` does opposite

Answer (score 0):

simply do with `split(" ")` the string with space then `join('-')`

> **Note** *: for unwanted space remove the [`trim()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjSnuuk48TVAhUVUI8KHe3CCqcQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_trim_string.asp&usg=AFQjCNEDh_x7JMeCVu0sakhKLDvxAVHYaw) function

```js
console.log('today is a sad day '.trim().split(" ").join('-'))
```

Comment: The OP example has a space after `day` like `today is a sad day `

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "today is a sad day ";
newstr = str.replace(/\s(?!$)/g,"-");
```

Comment: You better explain your solution instead of simply posting some code. Maybe it's worth reading [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to do this?

```js
str = "today is a sad day ";
toReplace = str.substring(0, str.length-1);
newstr = toReplace.replace(/\s/g,"-");
replaced = newstr + " ";
console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) you can use a `function (replacement)` to create the new substring to be used to replace the matches to the given regular expression. The arguments supplied to this function are described in the "[Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)".

Than you can work with the length of the string and the current `offset` to return the match or the desired replacement `'-'`.

Code:

```js
var str = 'today is a sad day ';
var result = str.replace(/\s/g, function(match, offset, string) {
  return string.length - 1 !== offset ? '-' : match;
});

console.log(result);
```